# Regex Adding Unnecessary Spaces During Replace

Tags: regex, vbscript, wildcard

I'm currently having difficulty with a VBScript I'm writing that contains several read and replaces from a  text file. The expression I'm using finds the expression and replaces it, but adds three tab spaces afterwords, making the original line below it mess up the formatting. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about:

Here's a pastebin of the before and after, rather than an image:
https://pastebin.com/Uw3H59QK

Here's my RegExp code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim strPath

strPath = SelectFolder( "" )

If strPath = vbNull Then
    WScript.Echo "Script Cancelled - No files have been modified" 'if the user cancels the open folder dialog
Else
    WScript.Echo "Selected Folder: """ & strPath & """" 'prompt that tells you the folder you selected
End If

Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )

    Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell
    Dim objFolderItems

    On Error Resume Next
    SelectFolder = vbNull

    Set objShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Please select the .dat file location folder", 0, myStartFolder)
    set objFolderItems = objFolder.Items
    If IsObject( objFolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing

    On Error Goto 0

End Function

Set re = New RegExp 'Replacing Position Lines
re.Pattern = "Pos = \((.*)\)"
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = True
For Each f in fso.GetFolder(strPath).Files
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "txt" Then
        text = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll 'reading the text file
        f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write re.Replace(text, """Position"" : mathutils.Vector(($1)),")
        count = count + 1
    End If
Next

Set reAngles = New RegExp 'Replacing Angles
reAngles.Pattern = "Angles = \((.*)\)"
reAngles.Global = True
reAngles.IgnoreCase = True
For Each f in fso.GetFolder(strPath).files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "txt" Then
    text = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
    f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write reAngles.Replace(text, """Angles"" : mathutils.Vector(($1)),")
  End If
Next

Set reNames = New RegExp 'Replacing Names
reNames.Pattern = "Name = (.*)"
reNames.Global = True
'reNames.Multiline = True
reNames.IgnoreCase = True
For Each f in fso.GetFolder(strPath).files
  If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = "txt" Then
    text = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
    f.OpenAsTextStream(2).Write reNames.Replace(text, """Name"" : ""$1"",")
  End If
Next
```

My best guess is that the wildcard is grabbing more info than needed...but I'm unsure how to fix that. I used a lot of these expressions in Notepad++ so I was hoping to translate them to a VBS easily!

Comment: It doesn't make sense: what you captured into Group 1, should not contain any line break chars, `.` does not match CR nor LF. It is impossible to repro.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's reproducible if the line ends with a single `CR` like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcxtz.png) @tyler.lagasse FYI

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Even if the string is `Text = "{" & vbCr & "    ""Position"" : mathutils.Vector((-143.257,35.1218,948.54828))," & vbCr & "    ""Angles"" : mathutils.Vector((0.0.0.0,0.0))," & vbCrLf & "    Name = MyName" & vbCr & "    myFunction255" & vbCrLf & "    MyArray = [1]" & vbCrLf & "}"`, the `reNames.Replace(Text, """Name"" : ""$1"",")` yields https://imgur.com/a/4yXv1Hj

Comment: @Tyler Please provide a reproducible text as a string literal and not an image.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my bad, I missed the quotes. You're right.